# MongoDB replica out of sync when performing a lot of inserts

Tags: mongodb, apache-pig

I have a three member replica set using MongoDB v3.2.4. Each member is a VM with 8 cores and 8GB RAM, and in normal operations these nodes are running very low in CPU and memory consumption.

I have a 60GB database (30 million docs) that once a month is totally reloaded by a Map/Reduce job written in Pig. During this job the cluster receives 30k insert/s and in a few minutes the secondaries becomes out of sync.

The current oplog size is 20GB (already modified from the default) but this does not resolve the replication sync issue.

I don't know if modifying the oplog size again will help. My concern is that the replication seems to be done when there is no load on the primary. Since my insert job lasts 1 hour does that mean I need an oplog the size of my db?

Is there a way to tell MongoDB to put more effort on replication and have a more balanced workload between accepting inserts and replication?

Comment: MongoDB doesn't replicate in realtime but it's more of eventually consistent. If primary is under a lot of load, this delay could prolong. Wait for sometime, and see if secondaries get consistent or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell mongo to put more effort on replication to have a more balanced workload between accepting inserts and replicatings these inserts?

To ensure data has replicated to secondaries (and throttle your inserts) you should increase your [write concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/#wc-w) to `w:majority`.  The default write concern (`w:1`) only confirms that a write operation has been accepted by the primary, so if your secondaries cannot keep up for an extended period of inserts they will eventually fall out of sync (as you have experienced).

You can  include the majority as an option in your [MongoDB Connection String URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/), eg:

```
STORE data INTO     
  'mongodb://user:pass@db1.example.net,db2.example.net/my_db.my_collection?replicaSet=replicaSetName&w=majority'
USING com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoInsertStorage('', '');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, forcing the replication on a majority of nodes should fix the issue by skipping the replication functionality. As deplaying the job is not an issue for us it should be acceptable to add this.